# how can we configure different unlock_in time config.unlock_in after user get passed config.maximum_attempts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails:How can we configure different unlock_in time config.unlock_in after user get passed
config.maximum_attempts using devise lockable module ??

I mean after the user passes maximum attempts second time the config.unlock_in should be different.

```
 # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
 config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

 config.unlock_keys = [:time]
 config.maximum_attempts = 10
 config.unlock_in = 1.hour
```

Comment: i meant after maximum attempts second time the config.unlock_in should be different

Comment: There is nothing built in -- the unlock_in setting is an app wide configuration setting.    There is also no way built in to determine the number of times a user has passed maximum attempts.  I would look at using the  Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch callback to a) start tracking the number of times the user has passed maximum attempts and then b) setting the lock_in appropriately.